# Handler,Looper,Thread так ктоже поток в андроиже?

Tags: java, android

Я не пойму,с джавы мне грят поток это `Thread`  но в андроиде я всё запутал ,прошу кто нибудь норм обьясните мне с примерами кто есть `handler` кто есть `looper` и как они связаны

Comment: http://javaway.info/mnogopotochnost-v-android-looper-handler-handlerthread-chast-1/

Comment: Поток в Андроиде - это Thread. Looper - это способ потокам обмениваться сообщениями, а Handler - способ сообщения обрабатывать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Handler берёт задачи потоков и складывает их в очередь, которую обрабатывает Looper - бесконечный цикл, который просыпается раз в 16ms, берёт задачу из очереди и отправляет её на обработку.
Подумайте, нужно ли вам так явно управлять потоками в ваших задачах, к примеру с помощью RxJava и его subscribeOn()/observeOn() можно очень удобно планировать потоки.

Comment: ну вообще скажу так )Rxjava это подход  и чтоб делать чтото в реактивном потоке надо чтоб минимум модуль приложения был заложен реактивно и тогда можно легче опрерировать с его операторами )я сам 2 года дергаю rx )